# Display Sitecore MVC rendering inside a Sitecore sublayout (Webforms page)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, rendering, sublayout

I've converted a sublayout to a MVC rendering and it needs to be statically bound to another sublayout.
The old sublayout was bound using

```
<sc:Sublayout runat="server" ID="myID" Path="file/path/tothe.ascx" />
```

Now that the component is a rendering i've tried

```
<sc:Rendering runat="server" ID ="renderingID" Path="file/Path/ToView.cshtml"/>
```

and

```
<sc:Rendering runat="server" ID="renderingID2" renderingname="ReturnToSearchLink"/>
```

Neither have been succesful. Just nothing shows up and the rendering doesn't get hit while debugging. Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the Box each page should be either WebForms or MVC.

Not advisable but if you really want there are solutions. Like the Hedgehog MVC aspx interop. I never tried statically bound, but you can give it a try.

See http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2012/december/mvc-webforms.aspx

See [Does anybody have experience in maintaining Sitecore MVC and Web Forms in a single solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016910/does-anybody-have-experience-in-maintaining-sitecore-mvc-and-web-forms-in-a-sing/34018205#34018205)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You cannot have MVC rendering inside WebForms sublayout. MVC and WebForms are different technologies.

What you can do in Sitecore is a site which contains both MVC pages and WebForms pages, but you cannot mix them on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

It's far from the most elegant solution but one option could be to use iframe's to embed the content between the different technologies.

If for example you have a webforms form you want in an mvc site, you setup a webforms page with just the form on and no margin or padding. On your mvc site you then use standard html iframe's to pull things in.

One challenge with this approach is getting the sizes of the iframes correct.

It definitely wouldn't be my first port of call in terms of solutions. However we've used in certain scenarios and it's saved us having to rebuild parts of the site in both technologies.